# Nuclear fusion with oriented nuclei?

Tags: nuclear-physics

In fusion terminology, what does it imply by taking orientational average of the fusion cross section when one of the nuclei has some static deformation/orientation? How is this average taken?

Comment: Presumably all orientations are equally probable, so the average would just be $\int d\Omega \sigma(\Omega)$.

Comment: I meant weighted average over nuclear orientation.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero What is it strong magnetic field? It non-QM analogy, I would think it changes the level distribution of the orientation.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you're accounting for the fact that the spins of the nuclei in the fusion interaction aren't (or are, perhaps) oriented in a particular way.  For instance, consider the D-T fusion reaction
$$
\rm ^2H + {}^3H \to {}^4He + n + 18\,MeV
$$
The deuteron $\rm^2H$ (or d) has nuclear spin $\hbar$, while the triton $\rm^3H$ (or t) has nuclear spin $\frac12\hbar$.
But the final state, $\rm^4He+n$, has spin $\frac12\hbar$.
If the deuteron and the triton happen to interact with their spins *aligned*, the minimum angular momentum in the system is $\frac32\hbar$, and the final state can't occur unless there's some orbital angular momentum to it.  Most of the fusion will occur from collisions where the d and t spins happen to be anti-aligned with each other. Neglecting to account the times when the d and t are aligned parallel, and the fusion coefficient is much smaller, would overestimate the cross section by a factor of $\frac23$, or thereabouts.